# Unable to update just specific row in p:dataTable

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

I am using `p:dataTable` with `scrollable="true"` and `frozenColumns="1"`. In **non-frozen column** I have `p:commandButton` **in every row**. On click of that `p:commandButton` I want to update just that **specific row** from which `p:commandButton` is pressed. What should I define in `update` attribute of `p:commandButton` or is there any other way which I should use?

Comment: Read about the PrimeFaces Search Expression Framework (also in the PF docs)

Comment: @Kukeltje, Thanks for the help. I read about it and used `@widgetVar(myTableWidget):@row(rowIndex)` but it is giving me error that 'it should be of type UIdata'. I can not use `@parent` to reach to that level because then I will have to use 10 `@parents`. I problem is there because it generates different table for frozen column. how should I proceed?

Comment: The error indicates your selector does not select a datatable. So try to fix that (quote the widgetvar?)

Comment: @Kukeltje, I have defined the `widgetVar="myTableWidget"` and `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"` in `p:dataTable` and defined the selector as `update="@widgetVar(myTableWidget):row(rowIndex)"`. Still not working.

Comment: I'm not sure the rowIndex works in this way defined client-side. Try if it works in the action/event on the server by passing the actual 'index' there in one way or another. And 'still not working' is kind of vague. Did you debug and see what the server actually tries to update?